# spring boot starter security post methods not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have added spring 'spring-boot-starter-security' to existing spring boot project ; after that the post methods in spring rest controller not working properly it shows a error something like this :

```
o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'POST' not supported


Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8080
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/authenticate
Request Method:POST
Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed
Response Headers
view source
Allow:GET, HEAD
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date:Wed, 14 Oct 2015 05:41:06 GMT
Expires:0
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
Request Headers
view source
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:47
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Cookie:_ga=GA1.1.630164096.1442901791; JSESSIONID=B9F1946DAE5BCA7772526CFC735616EC
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.125 Safari/537.36
X-ZUMO-APPLICATION:GSECUHNQOOrCwgRHFFYLXWiViGnXNV88
Request Payload
```

my controller method is this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/authenticate",method = {RequestMethod.POST})
public  LinkedHashMap<String,Object> authenticate(@RequestBody UserCredentials user){


    LinkedHashMap<String, Object> res =new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
    //business logic 
    return res;
}
```

pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.dfasfa</groupId>
    <artifactId>AdminDashboard</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>AdminDashboard</name>


    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>      
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableWebMvcSecurity

public class WebSecurityConfig extends  WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

 @Autowired
 private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

 @Autowired
 public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
     auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordencoder());
 }

 @Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
   http.authorizeRequests()
           .antMatchers("/addService").permitAll()
           .antMatchers("/app/*").permitAll()
           .antMatchers("/lib/*").permitAll()
           .antMatchers("/css/*").permitAll()
           .antMatchers("/styles/*").permitAll()
           .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
           .antMatchers("/getAllUsers").permitAll()
           .anyRequest().permitAll()  // for testing 
  .and()
//    .formLogin().loginPage("/login")
           .formLogin()
    .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
  .and()
    .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
   .and()
   .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/#/login")
  .and()
    .csrf();
 }

 @Bean(name="passwordEncoder")
    public PasswordEncoder passwordencoder(){
     return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }





}


import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application  {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        System.out.println("Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring Boot:");             

    }

}
```

if i remove all these security related stuff the code is working great . Is there any thing wrong in my configuration ? . the security login form and all other functionality is working great . but the post methods is not working .

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`.csrf().disable()` solved the problem

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception{
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe it would be best to just disable the e.g. /graphql endpoint, as explained in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38108872/767676

Answer (score 5):

Rather than disabling a security feature, it's better to search how to correctly implement it.
http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-csrf

In short you need to add an hidden attribute to all your POST forms.

```
<input type="hidden" th:attr="name=${_csrf.parameterName},value=${_csrf.token}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

This error is happening because when you add the Spring security to your classpath or `pom.xml` file, by default `csrf` gets enabled and you can only hit get method but for hitting put, post, patch, and delete rest endpoints, you have 2 options:

A) Disable the `csrf` like this

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/","/saveUser/**","/css/").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin();
}
```

B) Include `csrf` token while hitting from Postman Client

[Please Refer this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5I47.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide insight on what the UserCredentials object is ? I can't see it posted in the request too.

What you try to do rather reminds me what you can achieve using the **@AuthenticationPrincipal** annotation rather than posting content with a **@RequestBody**. This will yet imply some other mechanisms.

Anyway, two things :

1. What do you want to return from this controller ? Isn't there a **@ResponseBody** missing from the authenticate method ? Could you try adding that ?
2. Just in case : could you try to enforce the content-type consumed by your controller (**consumes** attribute of the **@RequestMapping** annotation) as sent in your request (already mentionned as application/json)

Answer (score 0):

As sudeep cv [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33130689/12999539), you can disable CSRF for your application

As user16115 [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48202078/12999539), it would probably better not to disable important security mechanisms.

Whether or not CSRF protection is important or not is dependant on your application. Spring Boot has a [recommendation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#csrf-when) for when you should or should not include it:

> When should you use CSRF protection? Our recommendation is to use CSRF
>   protection for any request that could be processed by a browser by
>   normal users. If you are only creating a service that is used by
>   non-browser clients, you will likely want to disable CSRF protection.