# How to enable POST, PUT AND DELETE methods in spring security

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I developed an application with spring boot, which was working fine. There is a restful controller. I tried to add spring security to some of the pages.
The rest controller's endpoint is

> `/api/greetings`

I configured the security settings in the class below.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home","/api/greetings").permitAll()
                //.antMatchers("/api/greetings","").permitAll()//can't do this
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }
```

Now, when I tried accessing the Rest endpoint, from a Rest-client(Postman), only the GET method is accessible and i am getting 403 Forbidden response if I try to POST, PUT or DELETE.

```
{
    "timestamp": 1467223888525,
    "status": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.",
    "path": "/api/greetings/2"
}
```

How do i solve this issue. I am new to Spring Security things.

Comment: Since mine is a non-browser application, disabling csrf wouldn't hurt, and it worked for me. I was curious, what if i don't want to disable csrf, or if my application is also web application, I found this link. Haven't tried it though but will try soon. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27182701/how-do-i-send-spring-csrf-token-from-postman-rest-client

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**UPDATE Answer**

If you're using Spring security 4, you can disable specific routes easily

```
http.csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/nocsrf","/ignore/startswith/**")
```

If not, you can enable/disable CSRF on specific routes using `requireCsrfProtectionMatcher`

```
http.csrf().requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(new RequestMatcher() {
    private Pattern allowedMethods = Pattern.compile("^(GET|HEAD|TRACE|OPTIONS)$");
    private RegexRequestMatcher apiMatcher = new RegexRequestMatcher("/v[0-9]*/.*", null);

    @Override
    public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {
        // No CSRF due to allowedMethod
        if(allowedMethods.matcher(request.getMethod()).matches())
            return false;

        // No CSRF due to api call
        if(apiMatcher.matches(request))
            return false;

        // CSRF for everything else that is not an API call or an allowedMethod
        return true;
    }
});
```

**ORIGINAL Answer**

You got an error because CSRF handling is 'on' by default with Spring Security.

You can disabled it by adding `http.csrf().disable();`.

But really, would you leave your application unsecured? I invite you to read  [this article](http://www.codesandnotes.be/2015/02/05/spring-securitys-csrf-protection-for-rest-services-the-client-side-and-the-server-side/) to protect your application against CSRF, even if your application is based on REST service and not form submission.

Comment: Is there other way, without disabling the csrf?

Comment: When I  used http.csrf().disable(); it also disabled all authentication.

Comment: If you want to use CSRF protection, then you will have to add a token to your HTTP POST requests. You can do this for example by adding a html input element of type "hidden" to the html forms. You can get the token from the CsrfTokenRepository. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-using